# Can't Create SQLite Database in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a database using SQLite

```
           try {
                _conn = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath); 
                _conn.CreateTable<Product>();                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
```

it is supposed to create database at `_dbPath` if it doesn't exist.

`_dbPath` value is `/storage/emulated/0/Phone Catalog/PhoneCatalogDatabase.db3` which is the default location when opening File Manager in Emulator(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXkNu.png)

I get exception saying: `Could not open database file: /storage/emulated/0/Phone Catalog/PhoneCatalogDatabase.db3 (CannotOpen)`

Any ideas why I get the message? Maybe there is a permission issue or something.

P.S. here is `Products` class if you need to see it

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had very simple mistake. `Phone Catalog` doesn't exist and that was the problem. I thought `sqllite` would create it but it only creates database file.